# Append from nth to nth index of a file with another file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

File 1:

```
1000000010019000000000012001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
1000000010019000000000012001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
1000000010019000000000012001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
1000000010019000000000012001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
1000000010019000000000012001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
1000000010019000000000012001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
```

File 2:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
ZAEDWQOIRPFJVND
SDEOIMFUJRKDMEU
WOQOEMFJCMSKSLD
XNCJFURYYEJWODK
EIWKEMDLDDLFMVM
```

Output File:

```
10000000100190000000000ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000ZAEDWQOIRPFJVND12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000SDEOIMFUJRKDMEU12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000WOQOEMFJCMSKSLD12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000XNCJFURYYEJWODK12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000EIWKEMDLDDLFMVM12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
```

Here i need to append the content of File 2 into File 1 from nth to nth index of File 1.

```
awk '$0=substr($0,1,10)"X"substr($0,12,length($0))' input.txt > output.txt
```

The above awk command works well for a file as input.But i need a variable as a input whose value will be changing for every line.

Read value from file 2 and append to file 1. From nth to nth index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Please try the following:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {line[FNR]=$0; next} {print substr($0,1,23) line[FNR] substr($0,24,length($0))}' file2 file1
```

yields:

```
10000000100190000000000ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000ZAEDWQOIRPFJVND12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000SDEOIMFUJRKDMEU12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000WOQOEMFJCMSKSLD12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000XNCJFURYYEJWODK12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000EIWKEMDLDDLFMVM12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
```

[Explanation]

- The script first reads "file2" and stores the lines in an array `line` indexed by the line number `FNR`.
- Next the script reads "file1" and insert the line in the array associated by `FNR`.

[Edit]

Here is a bash only alternative just in case:

```
paste -d "" <(cut -b 1-23 file1) file2 <(cut -b 24- file1)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{$23=$23 a[FNR]}1' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
10000000100190000000000ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000ZAEDWQOIRPFJVND12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000SDEOIMFUJRKDMEU12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000WOQOEMFJCMSKSLD12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000XNCJFURYYEJWODK12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000EIWKEMDLDDLFMVM12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=""        # set delimiters to null, each char is a field
}
NR==FNR {     
    a[FNR]=$0        # hash
    next
}
{
    $23=$23 a[FNR]   # append to right field
}1' file2 file1      # output
```

Tested with gawk, mawk, busybox awk and original-awk.

Answer (score 0):

As in @tshiono's comments, paste is the right tool for such cases.. If you want to try Perl, below would work

```
$ perl -e ' BEGIN { @f1=qx(cat manoj1.txt);@f2=qx(cat manoj2.txt); for(0..$#f1) { chomp($f2[$i]); printf("%s%s%s",substr($f1[$i],0,23),$f2[$i],substr($f1[$i],23)) }} '
10000000100190000000000ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
10000000100190000000000ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO12001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131

$
```

Inputs:

```
$ cat manoj1.txt
1000000010019000000000012001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
1000000010019000000000012001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
1000000010019000000000012001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
1000000010019000000000012001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
1000000010019000000000012001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131
1000000010019000000000012001011234567001011234567 2019013120190131

$ cat manoj2.txt
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
ZAEDWQOIRPFJVND
SDEOIMFUJRKDMEU
WOQOEMFJCMSKSLD
XNCJFURYYEJWODK
EIWKEMDLDDLFMVM

$
```